# How does post quantum key exchange in OpenSSH 8 work?

Tags: elliptic-curves, diffie-hellman, post-quantum-cryptography

OpenSSH 8 supports a post quantum KEX, namely sntrup4591761x25519-sha512@tinyssh.org

It says in its [description](https://github.com/janmojzis/tinyssh/blob/master/PROTOCOL.sntrup4591761x25519-sha512) that it is basically NTRU + ECC X25519. However, I have tried but cannot understand how it combines the two? My main source of confusion is that the description seems to be saying that the client creates just one set of keys (I am assuming NTRU key pair), but where is the ECC keypair and how is it being used?

Comment: Presumably it simultaneously does an sntrup4591761 key agreement and an X25519 key agreement simultaneously, and then authenticates the transcript of both of them, and derives a single session key by hashing the two key agreement results with a KDF?

Comment: @SqueamishOssifrage I compiled and ran it, to confirm that it generates two sets of keypairs, but I could only find one keypair (the X25519 one) ... isn't that strange? Also what do you mean by the 'transcript'? Thanks!

Comment: When Alice sends Bob her ephemeral public key $A = [a]G$, and Bob returns his ephemeral public key $B = [b]G$, and they derive the shared secret $k = H([ab]G)$, they presumably want to make sure they agree on the same shared secret and are not actually both talking to Mallory.  So Bob authenticates the transcript of everything that he sent and received on the network—sent $B$, received $A'$ (possibly equal to $A$, possibly forged)—and likewise Alice, using long-term identity keys.  Hashing a running transcript is a standard technique in modern protocols like TLS 1.3 and Noise.

Comment: As for what you got when you ran the code, I have no idea; it depends on what code you ran and how you ran it.  From your description of what you did I can't conclude anything.

Comment: @SqueamishOssifrage - Thanks for your explanation of transcript, very insightful. 

By 'it' I meant OpenSSH 8 :) ... I built it using the standard process (./configure, make, ...), and configured the sshd_config file to make sure sshd uses only the post quantum key exchange (KexAlgorithms sntrup4591761x25519-sha512@tinyssh.org). From the ssh client side I connected to the ssh server fine, but once I looked in the /etc/ssh/ dir, I only found the ed25519 keypair there, no sign of NTRU keypair.

Comment: The Ed25519 key pair is the _long-term identity key_ that is used to _authenticate_ the transcript.  X25519, and presumably sntrup4591761, are used to agree on an _ephemeral session key_ (what I called $k$ above), which they authenticate using the long-term identity key.  After the session, both sides—if acting according to protocol—will erase the ephemeral session key so that even if the server is subsequently compromised, it won't allow the attacker to decrypt past sessions.  There is no storage on disk needed for using X25519 or sntrup4591761 as such.

Comment: @SqueamishOssifrage - In that case, one could argue that the whole scheme is not really post quantum as only Ed25519 is used for authentication. As I understand, even if only the transcript authentication is compromised, the whole thing is compromised. Is that right?

Comment: Post-quantum _encryption_ and post-quantum _authentication_ are qualitatively very different beasts.  An eavesdropper _today_ can save ciphertexts to retroactively decrypt _tomorrow_ with a quantum computer.  But a forger _tomorrow_ can't retroactively change decisions that you made _today_ no matter how big and juicy their quantum computer is.  That's why developing and deploying post-quantum encryption and key agreement _today_ is so much more important than deploying post-quantum authentication.

Comment: @SqueamishOssifrage - Thanks a lot, that was very clear and insightful! I am still not sure if your explanation of using simulataneous key agreements is what OpenSSH 8 is doing (at least from their description), but makes sense to me :)

Comment: Note that X25519 static-static or static-ephemeral key agreement *can* be used to perform entity authentication of the party holding the static private key(s). You could use sntrup4591761 to (help) calculate the session keys. You would not need Ed25519 for signature generation. Just thinking along, I'll try to have a look at the actual protocol later.